# Pulling featured images from non-wp pages and setting them as a wp post featured image

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-featured-image

I am setting up a website that would partially link directly to various stories and articles on other websites. Is it possible for the featured image of each post be automatically set to the featured image/thumbnail from the website being linked to? What I'm looking for is similar to the way social media sites automatically show featured images of shared pages when a user posts the url. Please see the image attached to see what I mean.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Facebook share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYC1R.png)

Comment: Facebook is using the "og:image" meta property to show the image. Pages  add this property to their <head> and it isn't necessarily there.

You should fetch the HTML from the linked website and parse the og:image out to get the image URL.

Comment: Thanks! I've basically just been trying every plugin I can find that might help. I haven't been able to find any PHP to add to my child functions.php file that might work.   @Luka Peharda, thanks so much for the info. I have been looking online and can only find code to force Facebook to better show/pull images from my site. Any ideas on where to look to pull for code to pull from my end?

Comment: Sorry, I just found this page [link](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/02/25/how-to-collect-the-images-and-meta-tags-from-a-webpage-with-php/). I'll give this a try.

Comment: @Luke Peharda I am using a plugin called [Page Links To](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/) to link posts directly to external pages. I've been trying to find code I can add either to this plugin or my child functions.php file that would make all of these externally linked posts automatically pull the linked pages og:image meta info, but the only code I can find is for single external URLs. I would like all externally linked pages (at least via this plugin) to pull the thumbnail and use it as the WP featured image. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!